# Recurring Angular unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular.js v1.6 and keep running into the same error. I'm hoping someone can help me understand why I keep getting this error.

When I try to add 3rd party modules to angular, sometimes it works fine but other times I get an error saying "Unknown provider" when trying to inject the module into the app. This happens around a 50/50 rate.

Let me walk you through my process of adding modules:

I install using `npm install --save module-name` or sometimes `bower install --save module-name`.

I inject the module into my index.js file which looks like this:

```
angular.module('website', [
  'website.routes',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngTouch',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngResource',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ui.router',
  'duScroll',
  'module-name',
  function() {
    'use strict';
  }
]);
```

Then try to inject it into a controller for example:

```
angular.module('website')
  .controller('TemplateCtrl', ['$scope', 'module-name', function ($scope, module-name) {
    'use strict';
    ...
```

Like I said this method works fine about 50% of the time but the other 50% I get "Unknown provider", am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: variable `module-name` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Are you loading your js files asynchronously? For example with requirejs?

Comment: _"I get an error saying "Unknown provider" when trying to inject the module into the app"_ No, you get the error when you try to inject a module into a controller, which makes no sense. Services are injected, not modules.